# What's the latest version of Tomcat plugin for Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, plugins

I can only find [version 3.2.1](http://www.eclipsetotale.com/tomcatPlugin.html) which was released in 2007. Is there a new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using [Eclipse IDE for **Java EE** developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/heliossr1), you already get the tools to create Dynamic Web Projects and integrated servletcontainers (which are part of Web Tools Platform, WTP).

The latest [WTP release](http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/downloads/) is 3.2.2 from Sept 2010 and this supports up to **Tomcat 7**, but it's better to go for the integrated IDE rather than just the WTP.

**Additional Reading:**

[Migrating from Sysdeo to WTP - a bit old though](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.webtools/msg16810.html)